# Как прописать подключение Ethernet для Android?

Tags: android, сеть, shell, kernel, root

Есть Android 7.1.2, Kernel 4.9.95-android-x86_64, gcc version 4.6, cwhuang@android_x86. Поставлен на сервер, через ISO образ, полный доступ root к файлам. (Debug etc mode). Постоянно требует Wifi соединение, хотя Wifi на сервере вообще нет (адаптера/приёмника), есть Ethernet соединение со статичным IP адресом, и определенным Gateway, DNS Resolver'ом.

Собственно вопрос: Кто-нибудь знает куда прописывать эти самые настройки для того чтобы интернет заработал через Ethernet с определенным Gateway, DNS Resolver'ом, и статичным айпи адресом?

Answer (score 0):

Отсюда https://elinux.org/Android_Networking и отсюда http://www.android-x86.org/documents/nfs-how-to

```
netcfg eth0 dhcp;
или
netcfg eth0 up 192.168.0.2 
setprop net.dns1 your-dns-server;
route add default gw your-default-gw;
```

Опять же можно поместить в sh файл.

Comment: netcfg removed in Android 6 https://github.com/bbc/device_api-android/issues/92